# PowerShell, Exception-Handling: Create custom logfile from Set-ADUser

Tags: powershell, exception, active-directory

I'm trying to log errors in a custom logfile while making modifications to users from Active Directory.
Here's the code:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(objectCategory=user)" -SearchScope Subtree -SearchBase $searchBase | Set-ADUser -PasswordNeverExpires 0
```

Is it possible to check, whether the Set-ADUser command was successful for every single user and to write a custom string into a custom logfile, when the command encounteres an error? (e.g. insufficient access rights). Since those errors seem to be non-terminating, I have no idea how to solve this with try/catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enter code here` You could try using the `$error` variable to check if an error happens during each `PasswordNeverExpires` set.

```
$log = "C:\LogFile.txt"
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(objectCategory=user)" -SearchScope Subtree -SearchBase $searchBase `
    | %{
        $error[0] = $null            
        Set-ADUser -PasswordNeverExpires 0
        If($error[0] -eq $null){
            "User:[" + $_.Name + "] PasswordNeverExpires was set successfully" >> $log
        }
        Else{
            "User:[" + $_.Name + "] PasswordNeverExpires Failed to be set, Error:" >> $log
            $error[0] >> $log
        }
      }
```

Comment: Right idea, but I have two suggestions: 1. Rather than using `$error.Clear()`, which clears the entire $error list in the *parent* scope (the script or function doesn't have its own locally scoped instance), just set `$error[0] = $null`. 2. To get the error all on one line in the log file, change the **else** block to `Write-Output ("User:[" + $_.Name + "] PasswordNeverExpires Failed to be set, Error: " + $error[0].Exception) >> $log`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Worked perfectly for me. Just had to add the parameter -Identity `Set-ADUser -Identity $_ -PasswordNeverExpires 0` Also `$error[0] = $null` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `try..catch` you can force errors to be terminating errors by appending `-ErrorAction Stop` to the command, or by setting `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"`.

Answer (score 0):

Command  2> Some_log_file to redirect the errors.

Eg.

```
dir nosuchfile 2> test.txt
```